# Github Actions: Connecting to postgres database in diesel-rs

Tags: postgresql, rust, github-actions, actix-web, rust-diesel

I'm trying to run `cargo test` inside a CI workflow for my Actix Web app. Each test creates its own database by first connecting to the default database ("postgres") and then executing SQL queries.

This is the workflow currently used, the "Test postgres connection" runs successfully, but "Cargo test" fails:

```
on: [push, pull_request]

name: CI

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: rust:latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: stable
          override: true

      - name: Install PSQL
        run: |
          apt update
          apt install -y postgresql-client

      - name: Test postgres connection
        run: psql -h postgres -d postgres -U postgres -c 'SELECT 1;'
        env:
          PGPASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Cargo test
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: test
          args: --verbose
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

Here's an example of one of the tests:

```
struct Context {
    pub psql_user: String,
    pub psql_pw: String,
}

impl Context {
    fn new() -> Self {
        dotenv().ok();
        let psql_user =
            env::var("POSTGRES_USER").expect("POSTGRES_USER must be set for integration tests");
        let psql_pw = env::var("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
            .expect("POSTGRES_PASSWORD must be set for integration tests");
        let database_url = format!(
            "postgres://{}:{}@localhost:5432/postgres",
            psql_user, psql_pw
        );
        let mut conn = PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
            .expect("Failed to connect to the database 'postgres'"); // This panics

        // ...
    }
}

#[actix_web::test]
async fn test_create_task_req() {
    let ctx = Context::new("create_task_test");

    // ...
}
```

I assume the mistake is somewhere in my code as everything runs fine in the workflow until `cargo test`, that throws this error:

```
---- test_create_task_req stdout ----
thread 'test_create_task_req' panicked at 'Failed to connect to the database 'postgres': 
BadConnection("could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host \"localhost\" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host \"localhost\" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
")', 
tests/tasks_crud_integration.rs:42:14
```

When running `cargo test` locally, no problems occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With trial and error I ended up finding a working solution:

```
on: [push, pull_request]

name: CI

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
    test:
        name: Test
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        # Removed the container 'rust:latest'
        services:
          postgres:
            image: postgres # Removed version notation
            env:
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            ports:
              - 5432:5432
            options: >-
              --health-cmd pg_isready
              --health-interval 10s
              --health-timeout 5s
              --health-retries 5

        steps:
          - name: Checkout sources
            uses: actions/checkout@v2

          - name: Install stable toolchain
            uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
            with:
              profile: minimal
              toolchain: stable
              override: true

          # Removed 'Install PSQL' step as psql comes preinstalled in the postgres Docker Hub image

          - name: Test postgres connection
            run: psql postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres -c 'SELECT 1;'

          - name: Cargo test
            uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
            with:
              command: test
              args: --verbose
            env:
              POSTGRES_USER: postgres
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

As seen above, the seemingly most critical change was removing the rust container (that was unnecessary for the workflow anyway). Despite the solution being found, I still don't exactly know what in that Docker image caused the problem in the first place.